# Tooltip appearing under modal fancybox

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, fancybox, modal-dialog

I have a contact form on my website so people can write testimonials. The contact form pops up in a model box and it has tooltips that pop up on hover in some fields. The tooltips do work but it pops up behind the model box instead of in front. The example site is:

http://www.leadcomm.net/testimonials/

The modal pops up when the "write a review" image is clicked. The tooltips do pop up but you cant see them. If you hover over the radio box, you'll see it.

I tried adding a zindex but that didnt work.

```
$j(".ccf-tooltip-field").tooltip({
  position: "center right",
  offset: [-2, 10],
  effect: "fade",
  opacity: 0.7,
  tipClass: 'ccf-tooltip',
  zIndex: '100100',
});
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modal has a z-index of 111102.

Your tooltip class has a z-index of 1020.

If I give .tooltip a z-index of 111103 it works fine.

Comment: i gave it 111103 and it didnt work. then i gave it 191103 and it still didnt work. anything else i can try?

Comment: .tooltip is defined in http://www.leadcomm.net/wp-content/themes/pagelines/pagelines-compiled-css-1345847912/ and includes the z-index currently being applied.

Comment: you are AWESOME! thanks! I'm learning php-css-jquery as I go and it's a lot of info to take in. Thanks a million!